# type 'MethodChannelDocumentReference' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentReference' in type cast

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm updating my project using firestore and its the first time that I has this type of error.
Its very stange for me, I use firestore how the documentation saids and in other parts of my app Firestore don't had any error,
but in this part I use cloud functions to create a document and insert its reference in other. After I need to obtain the DocumentId but its said me this error "type 'MethodChannelDocumentReference' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentReference' in type cast"
I leave some screenshots.

[image: firebase user document =>coupon=>reference as reference]

This is my code in cloud functions:

```
exports.generateUserCode = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const { uid } = data;
  let coupon = shortid.generate();
  let user = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
  try {
    await firestore
      .collection("coupons")
      .doc(coupon)
      .set({
        owner: user,
        type: 0,
        value: 10,
        isPercentage: false,
        usersUsedIt: 0
      });
    await user.update({
      coupon: {
        reference: firestore.doc(`coupons/${coupon}`),
        uses: 0
      }
    });
    return {
      status: true,
      message: "codigo de invitacion generado",
      code: coupon
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error", e);
    return {
      status: false,
      message: "algo salio mal",
      code: null
    };
  }
});
```

This is the flutter code:

```
@override
  Future<UserModel> getUser() async {
    try {
      final authUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (authUser != null) {
        final user = await _firestore.document('users/${authUser.uid}').get();
        if (!user.data.containsKey('coupon') || user.data['coupon'] == null) {
          final couponCode = await _generateCode(authUser.uid);
          return UserModel.fromData(authUser, couponCode);
        } else {
          final coupon = Map<String, dynamic>.from(user.data['coupon']);
          final couponRef = coupon['reference'] as DocumentReference;
          return UserModel.fromData(authUser, couponRef.documentID);
        }
      }
      return null;
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString(), error: e);
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }
```

And this appears when I try to debug the code:

```
type 'MethodChannelDocumentReference' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentReference' in type cast
```

[image: MethodChannelDocumentReference]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of code.  It's better to copy the text of the code into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is the [solution](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2000) thanks for your help.